# How to change the scroll angle of scrollView in android?

Tags: android, uiscrollview, android-recyclerview, scrollview, android-custom-view

Is there any way to change the scrolling angle of the **ScrollView or RecyclerView** in android?
I know, by default some Android views will have horizontal and Vertical scrollings, but I want to know if it is possible to change the scroll in a particular angle or else diagonally?

How to create such custom components?

Here is an **example** with screenshots, I wonder how **Microsoft Excel Android App** achieved this.

Place your finger on the cell **D10** and drag the sheet towards the cell **A1**

[image]

Here is the result, the sheet scrolled diagonally, i.e., scrolled vertically and horizontally simultaneously

[image]

Comment: Did you try using a scrollview in a horizontal scrollview?

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work, even I tried recycler view inside a ScrollView @tyczj